# Can I install Windows XP on a new PC if I don't use the old one anymore?

Tags: windows

I have a Windows XP retail CD and it is installed on an old PC I dont use anymore.  Can I install it on a different PC that I will be using?  Will it still be considered "Genuine"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a full retail license, you can do this. At worst it will say that it has been previously activated. You will have to call Microsoft and explain the situation to them. Usually there should not be a problem as long as you are no longer using the other license, I have done this a number of times with XP and Vista.

With an OEM license, it is only supposed to be installed on one machine and never moved to another.

Comment: OEM licensed live and die with the hardware they are fist installed to.  That's part of the reason that you can get them so relatively cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Delete it from your old computer first, then as long as it is (as you say) a retail copy, you should have no problem installing it on a new computer. It is only a OEM based edition (sticker on the side of your machine) that is tied to a single computer.

If you have any problems, simply activate via free-phone and speak to someone who should either force the activation trough or give you a new licence key.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. In principle you should remove it from the old PC first, but I'd wait until you have a working install on the newer PC before you nuke the old one.

You will almost certainly need to call to activate it, but that is very straightforward.

The "Genuine" checks (as in WGA) are primarily to detect widespread pirated keys and cracked copies and the like, rather than small numbers of installs of a retail copy.

Comment: There is a difference between OEM and Retail version of Windows, which your answer doesn't mention.